# "it is not an interface in" error updating drupal (from 8.3.2 to 8.3.4)

Tags: drupal, updates, drupal-8

Trying to update drupal through drush, I get the following error:

> phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\BaseTag cannot implement
>   phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tag - it is not an interface in
>   /Users/team1/workspace/xxxxx/vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/src/DocBlock/Tags/BaseTag.php,
>   line 21

How can it be solved?

Comment: Should you be updating via composer instead of drush?

Comment: try running `composer update drupal/core` in the same folder as your composer.json. then `drush updb`

Comment: Now i execute:

1) composer update drupal/core
The result is:
`You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess`

2) drush updb
**The result is: the same error**

Comment: so, you are not managing your drupal site with composer? It seems to me that you are not using the correct version of phpDocumentor, but, I really don't know, since drupal 8 I have always used composers to install and update core and modules

Comment: I installed Drupal by downloading the zip package from its platform.
Unzip the package and install it via browser.

Having done it this way, can I make updates using composer? Do I need to change anything in my initial installation?

Comment: Well, this seems to be because you are trying to date core with drush, which updates core files, but not it's dependencies. Seems your best bet is to download the new drupal .zip (which should contain the new dependency versions).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and at the I discovered that upgrading to phpunit 5.7 (from phpunit 4.8) solved it.

Hope it helps anyone.